# Сортировка TreeMap по значению (BigDecimal)

Tags: java

Есть объект типа `TreeMap<String,BigDecimal>`, который необходимо отсортировать по значению. Пытался таким образом:

```
Collections.sort(map, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> a, Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> b) {
        return (a.getValue().subtract(b.getValue()));
    }
});
```

Но строка с `return` выдает ошибку, т.к. возвращается `BigDecimal`, а не `int`.

Попытка

```
return (a.getValue().subtract(b.getValue())).intValue();
```

не дала результатов.

Также не помогает запись

```
return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
```

Как можно произвести сортировку?

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться в итоге? Получить отдельно список отсортированных значений или же отсортировать `TreeMap` по значениям?

Comment: Отсортировать `TreeMap` по значению. То есть с "подвязкой" ключей. Задача вывести список, который я заложил в `TreeMap` по убыванию значения. Я могу заморочиться через несколько `ArrayList`-ов, но пытаюсь найти более оптимизированный вариант.

Comment: Что такое "подвязка" ключей? Пара "ключ-значение"? И вы ведь понимаете, что сортировка самого `TreeMap` по значениям - это что-то противоестественное и костыльное? Повторюсь: если нужно **отдельно** вывести пары "ключ-значение" с заданной сортировкой - это одно, а если отсортировать **сам** `TreeMap` - другое.

Comment: В продолжение моего предыдущего вопроса: есть список фамилий/чисел, которые я занес в TreeMap. К примеру пары, Petrov 10.1 , Reshetov 1.5, Sidorov 5.4, Ivanov 7.4, . Мне необходимо вывести отсортированные по значению пары: Petrov 10.1,  Ivanov 7.4, Sidorov 5.4, Reshetov 1.5. Аналогию выложенного выше кода (только через int-значения) я нашел здесь (на stackoverflow), но для BigDecimal его применить не получилось.В целом да, мне нужно отсортировать список значений, но так, чтобы при сортировки код менял местами и список ключей, чтобы в дальнейшем я мог вывести правильно пары "фамилия/число".

Comment: Давайте так. `TreeMap` сортируется по ключам. Пытаться отсортировать его по значениям - очень плохая затея. Либо используйте `BigDecimal` в качестве ключей, либо берите список пар из `map` и сортируйте его в отдельный список. Второй вариант я описал в своём ответе.

Comment: BigDecimal я не могу использовать в качестве ключей по некоторым причинам. Придется все-таки выгружать значения с карты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировка в `TreeMap` происходит по ключам. Пытаться сортировать его по значениям - плохая затея. В данной ситуации нужно либо `BigDecimal` делать ключами (если это возможно), либо список пар из `map` сортировать и сохранять в отдельный список.

Сохранение пар "ключ-значение" из `TreeMap<String, BigDecimal>` в `List<Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal>>` в порядке убывания значений:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal>> list = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> -e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

В таком случае для

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("a", BigDecimal.ZERO);
map.put("b", BigDecimal.ONE);
map.put("c", BigDecimal.TEN);
```

Вывод на экран `list` таков:

```
[c=10, b=1, a=0]
```

Comment: Отлично, то, что нужно, с одним "но": можно ли "=" заменить на другой символ? Мне нужно вывести через пробел.

Comment: @Murad это лишь стандартный вывод на экран `ArrayList` и `TreeMap.Entry`, полученный с помощью `System.out.println(list)`. Вы можете в цикле пройтись по элементам списка и вывести их ровно так, как вы хотите.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap Вы не сможете отсортировать, вы можете при создании задать ей Comparator, в котором установить свои правила сортировки.

---

Метод **compare** должен возвращать **int** значение в любом случае.

*Возвращает 0, если объекты равны, отрицательное число, если первый объект меньше второго, и положительное число, если первый больше.*

Воспользуйтесь методом **.signum()** который возвращает **int**

*-1 если число отрицательное, 0 если 0, 1 если число положительное*

---

```
return a.getValue().subtract(b.getValue()).signum();
```

---

Код который решает вашу задачу, просто добавляйте новые элементы и они будут автоматически подставляться по убыванию BigDecimal

```
TreeMap<BigDecimal, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<BigDecimal>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(BigDecimal o1, BigDecimal o2) {
        return -o1.subtract(o2).signum();
    }

});
```

Comment: Не проходит, выскакивает та же ошибка sort
`(java.util.List<T>,
java.util.Comparator<? super T>)
in Collections cannot be applied
to
(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.math.BigDecimal>,
anonymous java.util.Comparator<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.math.BigDecimal>>)
 
 reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Map<String, BigDecimal> conforms to List<T>`

Comment: `return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());`    возвращает int так же, но код не проходит

Answer (score 0):

Оберните BigDecimal внутри мапы в TreeSet и вопрос решится. 
`TreeMap<String, TreeSet<BigDecimal>>`